# CKEditor4 programmatically check text alignment

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm creating a custom toolbar using `CKEDITOR` APIs.
To check if a style is active I'm using this

```
const styles = {
 bulletedlist: new CKEDITOR.style({element: "ul"}),
 numberedlist: new CKEDITOR.style({element: "ol"}),
 bold: new CKEDITOR.style({element: "strong"}),
 italic: new CKEDITOR.style({element: "em"}),
 code: new CKEDITOR.style({element: "code"}),
 h2: new CKEDITOR.style({element: "h2"}),
 h3: new CKEDITOR.style({element: "h3"}),
 link: new CKEDITOR.style({element: "a"}),
 code: new CKEDITOR.style({element: "code"}),
 blockquote: new CKEDITOR.style({element: "blockquote"}),
 justifyleft:  new CKEDITOR.style({styles: {"text-align": "left"}}),
 justifyright:  new CKEDITOR.style({styles: {"text-align": "right"}}),
 justifycenter:  new CKEDITOR.style({styles: {"text-align": "center"}}),
 justifyblock:  new CKEDITOR.style({styles: {"text-align": "justify"}})
}

    for (let key in styles) {
     const $button = $(`[data-style='${key}']`)
     const element = editor.elementPath()
     styles[key].checkActive(element, editor)
        ? $button.addClass("button--active")
        : $button.removeClass("button--active")
    }
```

which works perfectly excepts for the last *four* styles ( text-alignments )

I'm applying text-alignments on every tag possible in my editor (`p, h1, h2, strong, em, etc..`) via

```
  editor.execCommand(style)
```

where `style` can be: `bold, italic, justifyright, justifyleft, etc..` and also this works perfectly.

My problem is that I'm not able to check if an alignment is applied on selected text.
I tried using

```
new CKEDITOR.style({element: "p", styles: {"text-align": "left"}})
```

and it works but that would mean creating one `style` per each `tag` used in the editor. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> but that would mean creating one style per each tag used in the editor.

That is what you unfortunately need to do. Styles in CKEditor are assigned to particular element so that you could see preview of such style assignment in dropdown.

When you open Styles dropdown, you will see styled `H1`, styled `span` or plain `code` style but you will not see style assigned to no element because there would be no way to present such a style.

Using dummy place holder like `P` but allowing style to be assigned to any element might sound ok for justify but in case of more complex styling, the final result would look quite different on `p`, `table` or `strong` and this is where we you would start going against wysiwyg and confuse users by presenting them previews which don’t match their results.

As I said at the start you need to have each style assigned to particular element and there is no way around it.